# Parse.com - after remove row from Installation class at Data Table my device token is not rcognize anymore

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, devicetoken

After remove row from Installation class from Data Table my device token is not recognize anymore.

The `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`method is not called anymore when the app load.
I'v tried to restore the iPhone, but nothing happen.

Comment: Hey How did you remove row from installation class?

Answer (score 0):

Try un-installing the application then reinstalling it. That should do the trick.